# Infinite dynamic multi-level nested category with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, categories, categorization

In my database structure is like this:

```
----------------------
| id | name | par_id |
----------------------
| 1  | AAAA |    0   |
----------------------
| 2  | BBBB |    1   |
----------------------
| 3  | CCCC |    1   |
----------------------
| 4  | DDDD |    2   |
----------------------
| 5  | EEEE |    2   |
----------------------
| 6  | FFFF |    5   |
----------------------
```

This I easily listed with PHP but I want to avoid PHP and with SQL directly made query that will return a hierarchy that looks like this:

```
---------------------
| id | name | level |
---------------------
| 1  | AAAA |   0   |
---------------------
| 2  | BBBB |   1   |
---------------------
| 4  | DDDD |   2   |
---------------------
| 5  | EEEE |   2   |
---------------------
| 6  | FFFF |   3   |
---------------------
| 3  | CCCC |   1   |
---------------------
```

I need to change order in table and add a level of depth like this:

```
From:                 To:
AAAA                  AAAA
BBBB                  -BBBB
CCCC                  --DDDD
DDDD                  --EEEE
EEEE                  ---FFFF
FFFF                  -CCCC
```

Is it possible in a single SQL query to do like this?

Comment: see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query  -  also take a look at the document mentioned there: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Is `-` your actual desired html output? Or do you have some html/css mark up that you want it to have?

Comment: @Sean no I just write for you guys to understand what I need. I will use level to made mark up of level with php/html/css